# three.js console error "scene.getObjectByName(...) is undefined" but everything appears to be fine?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm getting the console error:

```
TypeError: scene.getObjectByName(...) is undefined
```

on these two lines:

```
scene.getObjectByName('teapot').rotation.x += 0.005;
scene.getObjectByName('teapot').rotation.y += 0.005;
```

The relevant code where I'm loading the object looks like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load('obj/teapot.obj', function(object) {

  object.traverse(function(child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
      child.material = phongMaterial;
    }
  });

  object.scale.x = 2;
  object.scale.y = 2;
  object.scale.z = 2;
  object.name = 'teapot';

  scene.add( object );
 });
```

The scene itself is just a simple teapot rotating around, everything is rendering and behaving as it should as far as I can see.

I'm just wondering why the error?

Comment: I think you are calling that two lines before teapot object added to scene. add that two line inside your load callback. everything will work fine.

Comment: Resolved - Just realized it was because the object hadn't loaded yet. I added a check to only rotate it after it's been loaded.

Comment: @Durga yes! it was exactly that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load('obj/teapot.obj', function(object) {

  object.traverse(function(child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
      child.material = phongMaterial;
    }
  });

  object.scale.x = 2;
  object.scale.y = 2;
  object.scale.z = 2;
  object.name = 'teapot';

  scene.add(object);
  scene.getObjectByName('teapot').rotation.x += 0.005;
  scene.getObjectByName('teapot').rotation.y += 0.005;
});
```

You are getting `scene.getObjectByName('teapot')  == undefined` because you are calling that before teapot object added to scene. Call that inside load callback, so you will get teapot object and then add rotation to it.