# How to access Object3D material after adding the GLTF

Tags: colors, three.js, gltf

I want to duplicate my GLTF models with different positions/colors dynamically, to do so I have done:

```js
const L_4_G = new Object3D();
...
const multiLoad_4 = (result, position) => {
    const model = result.scene.children[0];
    model.position.copy(position);
    model.scale.set(0.05, 0.05, 0.05);

    //
    L_4_G.add(model.clone())

    scene.add(model);
};
...
function duplicateModel4() {

    L_4_G.translateX(-1.2)
    L_4_G.translateY(0.0)//0.48
    L_4_G.translateZ(1.2)

    L_4_G.rotateY(Math.PI / 2);

    scene.add(L_4_G);
}
```

I didn't find out how can I change the **Object3D** color from the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D), can you please tell me how can I do that? thanks in advance.

Here is the [full code](https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/JS_Tutorial/blob/main/threejs_webpack/src/js/glbLoad.js) that I'm using, and here are the [models](https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/JS_Tutorial/tree/main/threejs_webpack/src/assets/glb)

##### Update

1. I have seen this [solution](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-set-color-attribution-to-gltf-model/25749/2), to store a set of colors in the object's `userData` and choose the color later:

```js
L_2_G.userData.colors = {green : #00FF00, red : ..., ...}
L_2_G.children[0].material.color(userData.colors["green"])
```

But I'm getting an error that children[0] undefined, but I can see that this object has a child and a material, and color via the console: `console.log(L_2_G.children)`, `console.log(L_2_G.children.length)`--> `0`

2. Also I have tried `getObjectByName` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47919411):

```js
scene.getObjectByName(name).children[0].material.color.set(color);
```

which also reslts: `children[0]` is undefined, `scene.getObjectByName(name).children.length` is `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THREE.Object3D is a base class for anything that can go in a scene graph, including lights, cameras, and empty objects. Not all Object3D instances have geometry or materials. You may be looking for the [THREE.Mesh](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=mesh#api/en/objects/Mesh) subclass which does have materials and colors.

In general, code like `getObjectByName(...)` and `model = result.scene.children[0]` is very content-specific. The file might contain many nested objects, and `.children[0]` just grabs the first part. It's usually best to *traverse* the scene graph instead, looking for the objects you want to modify (e.g. looking for all Meshes, or Meshes with a particular name).

```js
const model = result.scene;

model.traverse((object) => {
  if (object.isMesh) {
    object.material.color.setHex( 0x404040 );
  }
});
```

Then you can either add the entire group to your scene (`scene.add(model)`), or just add parts of it. Keep in mind that adding meshes to a new parent removes them from their previous parent, and you shouldn't do that while traversing the previous parent. Instead you can make a list of meshes, and add them in a second step:

```js
const meshes = [];

result.scene.traverse((object) => {
  if (object.isMesh) {
    meshes.push(object);
  }
});

for (const mesh of meshes) {
  scene.add(mesh);
}
```

Finally, the position of an object is inherited from its parents. By removing the object from its original parents you might change its position in the scene. If you are planing to assign a new position to the object anyway, that is fine.